# Python Requests : How to send many post requests in the same time wait response the first and second

Tags: python

_1 = requests.post(logUrl,data=userDayta, headers=logHead)
i want send many post request like this in the same time

Comment: Threads, asyncio, multiprocessing...

Comment: `aiohttp` appears to be a good option for this:  https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods that work:

The reason that i posted both methods in full is that the examples given on the  main website throw (RuntimeError: Event loop is closed) messages whereas both of these work.

**Method 1**: few lines of code, but longer run time (6.5 seconds):

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()


async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        for number in range(1, 151):
            pokemon_url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            async with session.get(pokemon_url) as resp:
                pokemon = await resp.json()
                print(pokemon['name'])

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

# Wait 250 ms for the underlying SSL connections to close
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(0.250))
loop.close()
```

**Method 2**: more code, but shorter run time (1.5 seconds):

```py
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()


async def get_pokemon(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
        pokemon = await resp.json()
        return pokemon['name']


async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        tasks = []
        for number in range(1, 151):
            url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/{number}'
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_pokemon(session, url)))

        original_pokemon = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for pokemon in original_pokemon:
            print(pokemon)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())

# Wait 250 ms for the underlying SSL connections to close
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(0.250))
loop.close()
```

both methods are considerable faster than the equivalent synchronous code !!